# Maneuverability category step reduction beyond Clumsy

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In Pathfinder, flight maneuverability levels imply a bonus or penalty to their Fly skill when using their fly ability, according to this [table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Flight-Ex-or-Su-)

The spell Touch of Gracelessness, and I'm sure other effects, can reduce this rating by one step. So, let's say that a creature with a current rating of **Clumsy (-8)** is hit with this spell and fails her fort save; what happens to it?

The question, then, would be: **What happens to a creature with Clumsy maneuverability when some effect tries to reduce that maneuverability further? Another -4 penalty? Nothing? Can't fly anymore?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The creature receives the Clumsy maneuverability**

The bonus/penalty only applies to creatures that have a natural fly speed, thus they cannot be denied flying by taking this penalty. The spell does not state that they take a -4 penalty it simply states that their maneuverability gets reduced by 1 step. The skill section of the book describes the different steps below:

> A creature with a natural fly speed receives a bonus (or penalty) on Fly skill checks depending on its maneuverability: Clumsy –8, Poor –4, Average +0, Good +4, Perfect +8. Creatures without a listed maneuverability rating are assumed to have average maneuverability.

Your creature does have a natural fly speed, and because the chart does not list anything worse than clumsy, you can assume that you cannot get any worse, and thus you stick with the -8 fly speed penalty.